# GTX 1660 Ti Graphic card upgrade, unable to boot up the PC

Tags: boot, nvidia-graphics-card

I have recently purchased gtx 1660 Ti card for my PC, whose specs are given below

- Intel core i5 - 3570K Processor
- 8GB RAM, 500GB HDD
- Intel DH61WW Motherborad
- Some Old AMD Dedicated Graphic card.
- PSU Odyssey 450 W

I have connected the gtx 1660ti with given cables in box to my psu, as the psu doesnt have 8 pin connector, its stuck at intel motherboard page from which we can see boot menu, update bios, bios settings.. after a while it turns off again turns on and same story agin.

I have read that 450 W PSU is enough for gtx 1660 Ti, what could be the issue?

Update: I have upgraded my psu now to Corsair vs550, now I am able to boot the PC but the screen resolution is getting stuck at 1204*720 and also the booting is very slow it displays boot menu screen with code EB twice and then a black screen for few seconds then it boots up. Trying to install drivers but unable to do it cause of windows update issue. Windows is able to download the update but when restarted it’s not installing updates.

**Update : Thanks, yes updating the BIOS Did work, and i upgraded the PSU as well to 550W. The Bios was in Version 46 so had to follow the upgrade Tree suggested in Intel Website (46 -> 48 ->99 -> 120), if you don't follow this path it will not update the BIOS.**

Comment: The GTX 1660 Ti uses 83W at idle and 255W at load ([anandtech link](https://www.anandtech.com/show/13973/nvidia-gtx-1660-ti-review-feat-evga-xc-gaming/15)), so the PSU might not be enough for demanding tasks. Could you add screenshots of what happens when you boot? I also understand that you have connected it with a 6-to-8 power adapter (which should work fine).

Comment: @harrymc AFAIR 6-pin provides less power than 8-pin. If 6-pin was sufficient, the GPU would only have a 6-pin header. 6-to-8-pin adapter would be unsafe under high GPU load.

Comment: Is that a prebuilt pc that got upgraded? Asking this because my PC is a upgraded prebuilt PC and it wouldn't boot with another graphics card in it. I needed to update my BIOS to a custom one and so far it's working for more than 1 year. PSU can also be a problem (not providing enough power to the graphics card).

Comment: *Be aware*: Updating BIOS is an advanced process and if you do it wrong you can break the whole system.

Comment: @gronostaj: This worked for me with a GTX 1070. In any case, both 6- and 8-pins both have only three 12V pins, and both can carry much more than the rated 75W and 150W (which were made with old-style PSUs).

Comment: @user3576180 Can you clarify if the additional power is actually connected and how?

Answer (score 0):

1)
If you have bought the GPU of a suspitious site or a Japanese/Chinese site (where this is legale) it could be a Mining-Card and so could have the wrong Drivers installed or even worse no Drivers at all.

2)
But as I think that it probably has an Output for Screens it wont be a mining-Card

another reason why it could be happing is that one of the Transitors on the GPU has died so it wont start up.

3)
and the last reason I could think of is that you maby (even thou you have read that it is enought) have a to weak PSU maby you should check that again